# How to find a Window which should be visible on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, bash

In Ubuntu 14.04 I have Keepass2 in my Launchbar. I do execute Keepass and I can see it is executing by a small arrow. With statement :

```
ps - fu bernard | grep keepass2
```

results into :

```
bernard   2433  1697  0 16:31 ?        00:00:15 /usr/bin/cli /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe
bernard   3263  3212  0 17:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto keepass2
```

So Keepass is running.

Also with alt-tab I see Keepass. If I click on the Keepass icon still I am not switched to Keepass.

The same happened to me with XAMPP from https://www.apachefriends.org, and to the Ubuntu update manager. So it seems a general Ubuntu 14.04 problem.

With alt-tab I can switch to the running Firefox windows, so alt-tab itself seems to work.

I execute this in Virtualbox client. If I switch to other VB client, when I come back the Window is sometimes visible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a unity bug. If you try to restart unity it works correctly.

Hit `Alt + F2` and type `unity --replace` to restart unity.

After this, I think it will be OK....  :)

Comment: @ Pigeonaras I tried to do so, without result. Then I opened the terminal and tried to executed which the command which did generate a lot of errors. Like :OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).

Comment: Running it in Virtualbox?

Comment: @ Pigeonaras Yes, and alt-tab did not work anymore, as also all windows lost the close/minimize/ maximize buttons.